# binning multidimensional data

Tags: multidimensional-array, binning

I have a huge number of multidimensional data points. The points basically look like this:

```
[1.5,3.7,1.95,1.23] one point
[2.56,3.78,4.3,2.9] another point
...................
...................
so on
```

Sometimes the number of dimensions goes up to something like 20 and the number of points in this 20d space can go up to like 10 million.

I have to bin this data points considering all dimensions as "dependent". So the points have to move together. I have done binning in one-dimension, but although I have been racking my brains to come up with and algorithm, I haven't been successful so far in multi-dimensional case.

I couldn't find any java examples on multi-dimensional binning either. If anybody can give me an idea on how to tackle this issue in java that would be great help.

Comment: You should probably bin each dimension separately, then concatenate the vectors that you get. Probably, because it's not clear for what purpose you want to do this.

Comment: In particular, it seems you might be confusing the idea of "list of 20 numbers" with "20-dimensional point". What would it even mean to bin two items, one of which has a value for a specific "dimension", and one of which lacks a value for that "dimension"?

Comment: @larsmans As you said, if I bin each dimension separately wouldn't I be losing the the identity of the point?

I am a chemistry person. I am creating free energy landscapes for molecules, by adding constraints on angles, distances etc. these angles, distances etc. are the different dimensions that I am referring to. In order to calculate free energy, I need probability distributions. To get probability distributions, I have to create histograms. To create histograms I need to bin the data. That is where the binning comes in.

Comment: @twalberg I am not referring to a list of 20 numbers, in a 20d space I need 20 numbers to specify a point. That was what I was referring to. I am sorry if there was any confusion.

Comment: I cannot bin the data on separate dimensions, separately,  because it is like breaking up the x,y,z coordinates of a point, which destroys the identity of the point.

Comment: What I am describing is a situation like this. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/284246
I just want to have an idea as to how to implement this in java